# How to validate a custom widget?

Tags: 7, entities

I have created a custom widget that I would like to add some validation to. Specifically, if the widget is marked as required, to check that it actually has a value entered. I figure this should be pretty straight forward but Googling isn't returning any results that I am looking for. Probably using the wrong search terms. If someone can provide a link on how to do this or provide some hints that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Field API or Form API?

Comment: Good question. I am using this custom widget (date scheduler) in a form so I am guessing I need to use the Form API if I want to ensure there are values entered on submit. Having said that should it be a Field API if it is a particular widget? I am not sure which would be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

For a form API element, just set `$form['element']['#required'] = TRUE;`

More info: [#required](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#required)

> Indicates whether or not the element is required. This
>   automatically validates for empty fields, and flags inputs as
>   required.

For more control, consider an [#element_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate) handler

Note, for a custom element using [hook_element_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7), #validate and #element_validate callback handlers are supported there in the element definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a custom Form API (FAPI) widget, Drupal may not know how to correctly access its data, and thus the default validation (via setting `$form['element']['#required']`) will likely not work.

What you need to do is define your own element validation callback for that specific element. This can be done by setting the `#element_validate` attribute as such:

`$form['element']['#element_validate'][] = 'my_validation_function'`;

There is an example of the actual function implementation at: 
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate

Comment: I tried this method, but the issue I am having is that it reports an error (ie they haven't filled anything yet) when they haven't had a chance to fill it in. That doesn't make for a very good user experience. Is there a way around that?